# SQLite COUNT as type cast

Tags: sqlite

I was wondering if it is possible to cast an integer gotten from a count to REAL

something like the following (though this doesn't work)

```
SELECT CAST (COUNT (ColumnA) AS Count) AS REAL) FROM Table1 WHERE ....
```

I can convert the Count INT to real externally from SQL but I would like to cut down on the steps I need to perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A column alias must come after the *entire* expression:

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(ColumnA) AS REAL) AS Count FROM ...
```